# What’s the most common (and low cost) microprocessor with at least two threads?

Tags: threads

I want to make a next version of my current project. I’m hoping to use an Arduino compatible processor that also supports at least 2 processes simultaneously without using pro threading or any other software workaround. The more commonly used the processor is, the better the user support will be if something goes wrong.

Comment: What do you by "supports at least 2 processes simultaneously without using *pro threading*". What's "pro threading" in this context? Is that a specific library/framework?

Answer (score 5):

ESP32.  Dual core 240MHz, plus an extra XLP state machine.  Cheap and easily available on eBay/Amazon/Ali Express etc.  And with full Arduino support.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* also be interested in the Teensy 4.0. It *is* single-threaded (one CPU core), but it executes two instructions at a time if possible and runs at 600 MHz.

Beyond that, I only know of the ESP32 as well, for genuinely having two threads. Beware, if you want to design a product using that there might be extra hurdles with the FCC/whatever your country has since it is a radio emitter. Using an ESP32 module might simplify things, but I have very little idea how the legalities work.

It also seems a little wasteful to use a processor with Bluetooth and WiFi capabilities just because you need two threads, but it may be the only option.